# Search one of the field data Php / Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

I am working with my search button and i want to search one of my text input in my database. If I search in specific data like filling up the 3 columns is working. But when I am gonna search one by one data , all data is shown. **For example** I only search for the "accounting department" then accounting department should all appear, but when i do it the other department is shown. if I only click for selected date , all the dates are appeared. Search only for id is working but for department and date are not.

Here's my html code: What if I only choose to search the Department then it should be appear the matching records as well as date.

```
<form name="searchitem" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="searchid"> 
    Department : <select name="department">

    <option>Select Department</option>
    <option value="MIS">MIS</option>
    <option value="ACCOUNTING">ACCOUNTING</option>
    <option value="CNC">CNC</option>
    <option value="CONCESSION">CONCESSION</option>
    <option value="INVENTORY">INVENTORY</option>
    <option value="HR">HR</option>
    <option value="WAREHOUSE">WAREHOUSE</option>
    <option value="SALES & MARKETING">SALES & MARKETING</option>
</select>

Date Added : <input type="text" id = "datepicker" name="dateadd"><br><br>        
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
```

My `Php/Mysql` Code: I don't know what's wrong with the logic here: This should be working. Displaying output when only choose to search one field and when I run it, all data are displayed. I know you can help me with this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item_tb WHERE id like '%".$searchid."%' and department like '%".$department."%' and dateadd like '%".$dateadd."%' or id  like '%".$searchid."%' or   department like '%".$department."%' or date add like '%".$dateadd."%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: You really need to use prepared statements to ensure your query is properly escaped. Are you using PDO or `mysqli`?

Comment: only search on selected values, not on non selected ones

Comment: i am using Object Oriented

Comment: can you print the query and post here with the values which you are getting?

Comment: @Thejas , just check my link image shown above. if i fill up the 3 fields is working. But only 1 field is picked , it is not working.

Comment: why do you repeat the "and" and "Or" 's ?

Comment: @yesitsme , if i want only to search one field so there's an OR.

Comment: did you tried printing the query while executing the code?

Comment: @Thejas , yes. you can check it in my problem . the link image above. please check it

Comment: i have checked the link but did not saw any query

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written the query have to be changed. We need to use some PHP code too to make this work correctly.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item_tb where 1=1 ";
if($_POST["searchid"]){
  $sql .= " and id '%".$searchid."%' "
}
if($_POST["department"]){
  $sql .= " and department '%".$department."%' "
}
if($_POST["dateadd"]){
  $sql .= " and dateadd'%".$dateadd."%' "
}
```

Hope this helps